# How to set hdparm in boot? 14.04+

Tags: 14.04, boot, scripts, hard-drive, hdparm

I want to disable the Advanced power management of the hard disk in Ubuntu 14.04.

The hdparm command is working:

```
costales@desktop:~$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb | grep -i "Advanced power management level"
    Advanced power management level: 128
costales@desktop:~$ sudo hdparm -B 255 /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
 setting Advanced Power Management level to disabled
 APM_level  = off
costales@desktop:~$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb | grep -i "Advanced power management level"
    Advanced power management level: disabled
costales@desktop:~$
```

But, how can I set it in the boot? I tried in the /etc/rc.local without luck:

```
costales@desktop:~$ tail /etc/rc.local -n 4
# By default this script does nothing.
sudo hdparm -B 255 /dev/sdb
exit 0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tested to make sure 255 is the one you need? Some computers do not respond to 255 and you need to set 254 to disable apm.

Comment: The reason I say this is because on many models of laptops, setting APM to 255 doesn't actually disable apm because I believe apm is built into the kernel or something. All I know is that I have tried setting my laptop to 255 and I check the cycled spin downs and spinups and see the number constantly increasing whereas, setting the number to 254 prevents spindown and apm functions from taking place, even though 255 reports disabled and 254 reports apm level 254.

Comment: You can verify this by checking your load cycle count when you run the command: `sudo smartctl -A /dev/sdb` Run this command once, wait a little while and then run it again a bit later. This number should not change if it really is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to prevent apm actions on /dev/sdb.

Run the following commands. Set to 254 or 255 depending on your manufacturer and based upon the gathered results from running the command:

```
sudo smartctl -A /dev/sdb | grep Cycle
```

These numbers should not change if apm is disabled while your computer is on and has not been turned off or hibernated.

Here, I will provide an example for the 254 option as I have seen that in most instances, it is necessary to use this option as 255 does nothing to prevent apm from non-hdparm applications or code or whatever.

```
sudo hdparm -B 254 /dev/sdb*
echo "/dev/sdb* {" | sudo tee -a /etc/hdparm.conf
echo "  apm = 254" | sudo tee -a /etc/hdparm.conf
echo "  apm_battery = 254" | sudo tee -a /etc/hdparm.conf
echo "}" | sudo tee -a /etc/hdparm.conf
sudo sed -i 's/#apm = 255/apm = 254/g;s/#apm_battery = 127/apm_battery = 254/g' /etc/hdparm.conf
```